# Using Pixi.js with Adobe AnimateCC Canvas - Displacement map

Tags: canvas, pixi.js, animate-cc

I would like to know how to be able to target an existing canvas div with an id of 'canvas' from within the AnimateCC code panel?

Currently the code sample I was experimenting with, only outputs to an additional canvas element

[Download example files here](https://lion.box.com/s/8baodxg21719lid01mh882n8w313wig6)

This is what I have also tried to target the existing canvas...

```
(function() {


var pixiHolder = document.createElement('pixiHolder');

pixiHolder.width = 300;
pixiHolder.height = 250;

document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(pixiHolder);

renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(pixiHolder.width, 
pixiHolder.height, {

view: pixiHolder,
transparent: false,
backgroundColor: 0x223344

});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
var renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(canvas.width, canvas.height, {
  view: document.getElementById("yourCanvas"),
  transparent: false
});
```

Comment: Hm, still no luck. Did you have this working with my sample files? Thanks